# Canon 650D HD movie stop after 10-12 sec

Tags: video, dslr, full-hd, canon

I have a **Canon-DSLR-650-D**,the problem is when I start recording move at **HD** it will automatically stop after 10-12 sec, whereas at **640** resolution it is working fine.
My Memory card is empty..can anyone help me is there any issue with my **SD card** or what ???